# Memory error when reading each line in large file

Tags: python, out-of-memory

I'm trying to search pi for a specific set of numbers and have it return the start and end index position. The code works fine with 1 million digits of pi but as soon as I try 1 billion I get a memory error (The 1B is 953mb).

```
import re

search_inp = raw_input("What do you want to find?: ")
with open("1B_Pi.txt") as infile:
    for line in infile:
        string = str(line)
        a = re.search(search_inp, string)
    else:
        print (a.start()),(a.start())+len(search_inp)
        print (line[(a.start()):((a.start())+len(search_inp))])
```

Outputs: for line in infile: MemoryError

Comment: Are all the digits on one line?

Comment: @shadowtalker no, but there are a lot of digits on one line

Comment: `for line in infile` iterates through every line of `infile`. Perhaps you should try writing the contents of your `txt` file to memory with `digits = infile.read()`, then outside your `with` block, search through `digits`. If that still raises a `MemoryError`, then your computer just doesn;t have enough memory to handle 1 billion digits

Comment: @Joel should 16gb of ram be enough?

Comment: I have no idea, you should experiment and find out...

Comment: @Joel I tried your suggestion and Sure enough I received MemoryError but I checked both files and the line lengths are the same.

Comment: @Joel well, that doesn't make sense. If you wanted to read every line, then you should iterate lazily over the file iterator, using `for line in infile:` instead of reading the whole thing into memory

Comment: `string = str(line)` is redundant. Remove it and test this again.

Comment: And the logic for searching the file may be incorrect. After doing `re.search`, should you not be checking if it is found and break when you do so?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga that's the point, OP shouldn't be reading line-by-line

Comment: @HoneyCentaur the line lengths might be the same, but which file has more lines?

Comment: @Joel well the 1 billion digits of pi has more lines than the 1 million digits of pi.

Comment: @HoneyCentaur the file with 1 billion digits requires roughly 1000 times the memory as the file with 1 million digits. That's your problem